# Estimate car width from the back using opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dimension

I have an image of the car from the back like below where number plate is clearly detectable and its dimensions are known to me.
[image]

Here is the original image of the car 
[image]

I have detected the corners in blue circles after removing the background (masking) and I am trying to calculate the distance on the basis of number plate known dimensions. Please guide me that is it the correct way of estimating the width of the car ? Definitely it is not best way but in this case would it give me correct estimate ? Also, please guide me how should I detect the number plate without running any classification algorithm ? I do not have many images of car to run train the algorithm. I just want to detect the plate (based on some logic) and transform the back dimensions from the number plate.

For example,

```
number_plate_dimensions = (width, height) = (10, 4)
image_number_plate_dimensions (from Euclidean distance) = (width, height) = (7.1, 1.6)
So width_factor = 10/7.1 = 1.408
```

Now, I take the Euclidean distance of the two corners in blue and multiply the result by this width_factor (1.408) to estimate the dimensions of the car. 
Is this method correct ?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As a most basic beginner step, you want the homographic transform of the detected numberplate to the known dimensions. You apply the same transform to the outline of the car and get the dimensions as a result.

You could definitely do a first order approximation as shown by your euclidean approach, but especially with extreme angles (e.g. from above the car), this will introduce some serious distortion.

I use the Lukas-Kanade optical flow tracking algortihms to do the underlying homographies, but google will lead you to a lot of approaches using homographies with opencv.

An example of how a homography can be calculated in a simple way together with an example is [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: You could go even further, estimating the 3D shape of the car if you have enough pictures from the same car.

Comment: I have pictures only from 2 angles one angle is from the back to determine the width and one angle is from the side to determine length and height. And from each angle I have 2 pictures, one few meters behind and other few meters forward. Would this information be enough to estimate a 3D model ?

Comment: It should be enough to calculate bounding boxes in which the car fits in 3D.